# Use XSLT to insert elements conditionally?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to insert "place holder" elements in one or more nodes, based on the sibling node with the greatest element count.

Here's what I have:

```
<main>
<program>
    <product>1</product>
    <product>2</product>
    <product>3</product>
</program>
<program>
    <product>1</product>
</program>
```

Here's what I want:

```
<main>
<program>
    <product>1</product>
    <product>2</product>
    <product>3</product>
</program>
<program>
    <product>1</product>
    <product>dummy</product>
    <product>dummy</product>
</program>
```

As you can see, the XLST should insert two dummy elements into the second  node, because a sibling  node has three elements. How can I make XSLT insert dummy elements into nodes with lesser element counts?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there going to be only 2 `program` nodes? What if a third `program` node with 4 elements is added, do the first and second have to have additional "dummy" nodes added?

Comment: There can be any number of program nodes and each program node may have any number of elements.

Comment: Which is correct, the first or the second question? Or both?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my reply.

Comment: Just to clarify: in the event of a third 'program' node being added with 4 elements, a "dummy" node would have to be added to both the first and second 'program' nodes? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The third program node would then have the greatest element count, which would mean the first program node would need one dummy element added and the second program node would need three dummy elements added. The end result: all program nodes contain four elements.

Comment: Could you have a look at my answer and get back to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a working XSLT 2.0 solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="countMax" select="max(//program/count(product))" />

        <main>
            <xsl:for-each select="/main/program">
                <xsl:variable name="currentCount" select="count(./product)" />
                    <program>
                        <xsl:for-each select="./product">
                            <product><xsl:value-of select="." /></product>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$currentCount+1 to $countMax">
                            <product><xsl:text>dummy</xsl:text></product>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </program>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </main>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it's likely there are better answers out there.

Comment: I should be able to get a working XSLT 1.0 solution if you're interested.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, you can use the "max" function, so the "countMax" variable can be written as `<xsl:variable name="countMax" select="max(//program/count(product))" />`

Comment: @TimC Thanks for the info, I edited my response (I was using `max(count(...))` and couldn't get that to work, so went with previous solution). Does the variable need to be set as `as="xs:integer"`?

Comment: I tested it without it, and it seemed to work (although note that your have the version number of the stylesheet as "1.0" and the xml version as "2.0" which is the wrong way around....). Also, I think you need your "for-each" loop to start at `$currentCount + 1` because otherwise it ends up inserting an extra dummy element.

Comment: @TimC Oops ... corrected. Thanks, my response has been edited. I looked at the question as an exercise to do, so I'm glad the solution passed your test :)

Comment: Anton - Thank you very much for your help. I've edited this question to include a reference to xquery.